# Splitting Dataframe into pieces of for example 8 hours

Tags: r, datetime, split

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [With R: Split time series data into time intervals (say an hour) and then plot the count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649019/with-r-split-time-series-data-into-time-intervals-say-an-hour-and-then-plot-t)

I have data with multiple columns and values, all having a timestamp every 10 seconds. The data spans several days, but I want to split it into pieces of for example 8 hours. I have been looking at split() and the plyr package but cannot find a proper way of doing this.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post a small example dataset so we know what the timestamp looks like?

Comment: The timestamp has the following format: 2012-10-24 08:47

Comment: See `?cut.POSIXt` and a possible related example at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13650168/1270695. Basically, if you have an actual date format, you should be able to use something like `split(mydata, cut(mydata, breaks="8 hours"))` to get subsets of your data.