# Make time series data discrete in R, when there are irregular times records per bin and additional location data

Tags: r, time-series

I am looking for a way to make regular discrete time intervals in R with data that is irregular and includes location information. (For example, 10 second intervals, and only the first location information per time interval).

The input data looks like this:

```
ID          Time           Location Duration
```

1   Mark 2015-04-15 23:55:41        1   145448
2   Mark 2015-04-15 23:58:07        9    1559
3   Mark 2015-04-15 23:58:08        9    2279
4   Mark 2015-04-15 23:58:11        9    557
5   Mark 2015-04-15 23:58:11        3    10540
6   Mark 2015-04-15 23:58:22        9    1783
7   Mark 2015-04-15 23:58:24        9    8706
8   Mark 2015-04-15 23:58:32        9    555
9   Mark 2015-04-15 23:58:33        2    124137
10  Mark 2015-04-16 00:00:37        2    7411
11  Mark 2015-04-16 00:00:37        20   7411

and the desired output would be:

```
ID          Time           Location
```

1   Mark 2015-04-15 23:55:40        1
2   Mark 2015-04-15 23:55:50        1
3   Mark 2015-04-15 23:56:00        1
...
16  Mark 2015-04-15 23:58:00        9
17  Mark 2015-04-15 23:58:10        9

Any ideas?

Comment: look for example on this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649019/with-r-split-time-series-data-into-time-intervals-say-an-hour-and-then-plot-t) question for breaking time series into bins

Comment: Please use `dput(data)` and copy in the output to make it easier for us to look at your data.

Comment: Thanks! using intervals <- data.frame(cut(ID$Time, breaks="10 secs")) then I sort duplicates with a for loop.