# Is there any way that i can perform sum instead of count using cut or any other function using R

Tags: r

By referring the below link am able to find frequency count of columns using cut.

[reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649019/with-r-split-time-series-data-into-time-intervals-say-an-hour-and-then-plot-t)

Am able to get output as using above link as

```
var1                 freq
2015-10-01 10:00:00  10
```

But i require sum of those record column values in that hour. Here for example i have a column **value_column** with different time intervals in a day. How to do sum of those values and display it in separate columns.

```
value_column  date_time
14            10/1/2015 10:00
10            10/1/2015 10:02
16            10/1/2015 10:03
9             10/1/2015 10:04
1             10/1/2015 10:05
5             10/1/2015 10:06
13            10/1/2015 10:07
21            10/1/2015 10:08
18            10/1/2015 10:09
16            10/1/2015 10:10
```

Expected output

```
sum_value_column  date_time
123               10/1/2015 10:00
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably try with :

```
df1$date_time <- as.character(df1$date_time, stirngAsFactors = F) 

df1$date <- str_split_fixed(df1$date_time, " ")[,1] 

df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date, "%d/%m/%Y") 

df1$time <- str_split_fixed(df1$date_time, " ")[,2]

total_table <- aggregate(df1$value_column, by = list(df1$date, df1$time), FUN =sum)
```

Probably this is a bit big but I can use both date and time for any further analysis.

Answer (score 3):

We can convert the 'date_time' column to `POSIXct` class, replace the minute part with `00` using `format`, group by that variable and get the `sum` of 'value_column' with `summarise`.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df1 %>%
     group_by(date_time = format(as.POSIXct(date_time, 
                           format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'), '%m/%d/%Y %H:00')) %>% 
     summarise(sum_value_column = sum(value_column))
#            date_time sum_value_column
#            (chr)            (int)
#1 10/01/2015 10:00              123
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(value_column = c(14L, 10L, 16L, 9L, 1L, 
5L, 13L, 
21L, 18L, 16L), date_time = c("10/1/2015 10:00", "10/1/2015 10:02", 
"10/1/2015 10:03", "10/1/2015 10:04", "10/1/2015 10:05",
"10/1/2015 10:06", 
"10/1/2015 10:07", "10/1/2015 10:08", "10/1/2015 10:09",
"10/1/2015 10:10")), .Names = c("value_column", "date_time"), 
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Answer (score 3):

For SQL users, assuming the input is the data frame `data`:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select substr(date_time, 1, instr(date_time, ':')) || '00' date_time, 
              sum(value_column)
       from data
       group by substr(date_time, 1, instr(date_time, ':')) || '00'")
```

Alternately, we could factor out the complex expression into a nested select statement like  this:

```
sqldf("select date_time, 
              sum(value_column)
       from (select substr(date_time, 1, instr(date_time, ':')) || '00' date_time,
                    value_column
             from data)
       group by date_time")
```